# REDIS in python

Tags: python, redis

I have never used REDIS so excuse my ignorance. REDIS is supposed to store (keys,values) to disk and it's better in speed than mysqldb in queries. My questions are :

-Can I save the REDIS db not in the primary disk but in an external (should i do this by installing redis not in the primary's disk location ?)

-Is there an API where I can see the stored data (something like sql's phpmyadmin ) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Redis is a *in-memory* DB, that is, all the DB is stored in memory but It save the data to disk based on several algorithms.

So, to store in a different disk you only need to set the destination in your redis config file.

Example of redis conf file: https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.6/redis.conf

```
dbfilename /my/path/dump.rdb
```

About the redis API, you can use the redis-cli, It's a friendly Command Line interface for redis that It's included in the redis installation. But if you prefer something more "Graphical", take a look to http://redisdesktop.com/ a Open Source GUI for Redis.

I recommend to you a look to [Redis QuickStart guide](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart)

Comment: To find out how redis save to disk, search for "SNAPSHOTTING" section in config file. The process is managed by redis based on your config. For further details: http://redis.io/topics/persistence

Comment: changed value from:

dir /var/lib/redis

to

dir /media/D60A6CE00A6CBEDD/redis_db

But I see that when it runs the python script the dump.rdb file is stored inside the dir /home/user I initiate the redis server by this :

nohup redis-server &

Comment: You need to pass it the config file: "redis-server /path/myconfigfile.conf", see "Starting Redis" section in redis QuickStart guide